# How to ignore a return value in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm working with some code which calls ADJUST-ARRAY. I am getting a warning message from the Lisp interpreter (CMUCL) that the return value of ADJUST-ARRAY should not be ignored.

In the code I am working on, ADJUST-ARRAY modifies its argument in place, if I am not mistaken. So it's not necessary to do anything with the return value. Is there a designated way to ignore a return value in Common Lisp? Of course, I could assign the return value to some variable, and then ignore the variable. But that feels clumsy.

I could also assign the return value to the ADJUST-ARRAY argument, something like:

```
(setq my-array (adjust-array my-array ...))
```

but that seems to suggest that I'm not sure if ADJUST-ARRAY will modify MY-ARRAY in place.

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: `ADJUST-ARRAY` is not required to always modify the argument array. From the [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_adjust.htm): "The result is an array of the same type and rank as array, that is either the modified array, or a newly created array to which array can be displaced, and that has the given new-dimensions. "

Comment: Is there any way to predict whether the modified array or a new array is returned? That is, does ADUST-ARRAY always return the modified array under some circumstances and always return a new array under some other circumstances.

Comment: The spec does not specify circumstances where it has to do one or the other. [`ADJUSTABLE-ARRAY-P`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_adju_1.htm#adjustable-array-p) will return true for arrays that **may** be modified in place, but the spec doesn't actually say that the array has to be modified in place. It's up to the implementation.

Comment: It might be useful to also answer the original question. It's usually possible to surpress compiler warnings, The specific warning is non-standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specification of `adjust-array` is that the adjusted array is the one returned.

What you can expect of the argument array afterwards to be is a bit complicated and may differ between implementations in some cases.

Just use the one returned.  You might use `setf` to modify or `let` to create a binding.

Comment: Yeah, I am going to change the code so that the return value is used. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. As [the documentation](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_adjust.htm) states:

> The result is an array of the same type and rank as array, that is
>   either the modified array, **or a newly created array** to which array
>   can be displaced, and that has the given new-dimensions.

If the result is a newly created array then of course the function would have had **no effect** on the argument.

Common Lisp almost always require you to use the returned value rather than old bindings in order to have portable code.

Comment: I'm going to change the code so that the return value is used. Thanks for your help.